# How to get all SKU's of simple products?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, sku

I have too many child products. I would like to see all child product's **sku**.

Any one help me to get all simple product **sku**.

Comment: In which format you want the list of SKUs?

Comment: please check the answer and let me know

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get the all products's sku's by exporting method. for that,
2. Goto admin->system->import/export->dataflows->export all products

You can see the sku's in downloaded file in csv format of all products.

Comment: thanks for reply. I need Just  all simple product **sku**  name  csv file format

Comment: yes. thats y i gave this answer. check my updated answer.

Comment: @ Teja bhagavan Kollepara thanks but i would like to get only  simple product sku by programming

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
$childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($ConfigurableProductId);
foreach($childIds as $pid){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
    echo $product->getSku(); 
}
```

2nd way  also this code also works

```
$configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is productId 
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$configurableProduct);   
foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    echo $child->getSku();
}
```

3Rd option

```
$configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is productId 
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')                        
            ->getUsedProductCollection($configurableProduct)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($childProducts as $product){
   echo $product->getSku(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks bro. 
please can You let me know where i have to create file to write this code .
so i can get **sku** of All Simple product thanks

Comment: @Grace Where you have written rest of the code ??

Comment: i mean where  can i past this code. I am new in magento I haven't idea about it

Comment: Your first method has one small error.
`foreach($childIds as $pid) { .. }`  should be:
`foreach($childIds[0] as $pid) { .. }`